# Cookie Consent Banner LinkedIn Tag

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following Javascript related problem problem:
The code below is working as cookie consent. Basically i am storing a cookie called "LinoPro_Consent" whenever a user saves the preferences through out my cookie banner. However only the scripts get loaded when they are inside the acceptFn event. Everything works fine expect for the LinkedIn Cookies. I tried to integrate them into the acceptFn event by simply putting the code inside the function, but this does not seem to work and the linkedin script is not loading in the network tab. However if i exclude the linkedin scripts outside the acceptFn event and put it below, the scripts are loading and the linkedin cookies are placed but without the given consent from the user. I want the LinkedIn-Cookies to work the same way as the GT and GA Cookies but all I tried does not seem to work. In the code below i tried to declare a variable that gets set to true everytime the acceptFn is called and i placed a if condition above the Linkedin part to make sure consens is given first but as you can see in network tab of your browser it is still not working properly.

For a better understanding you can also visit testumgebung.linopro.de to see the applications and cookies firing.

```
const cookieStorage = {
    getItem: (key) => {
        const cookies = document.cookie
            .split(';')
            .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
            .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value }), {});
        return cookies[key];
    },
    setItem: (key, value) => {
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`
    },
};

const storageType = cookieStorage;
const consentPropertyName = 'LinoPro_Consent';


const shouldShowPopup = () => !storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);
const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, true);
const declineStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, false);
const editStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, 'edited');

window.onload = () => {
    const consentPopup = document.getElementById('consent-popup');
    const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');
    const declineBtn = document.getElementById('decline');
    const editBtn = document.getElementById('edit');
    let LinkedInPlatzhalter = 'false';


    const acceptFn = event => {
        saveToStorage(storageType);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        LinkedInPlatzhalter = 'true';
        

        // Google Tag Manager START //
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
                'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
            }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-TBTC37T');
        // Google Tag Manager END//

        // Google Analytics START //
        // Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
        var gaProperty = 'UA-114511820-1';

        // Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
        var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
        if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
            window[disableStr] = true;
        }

        // Opt-out function
        function gaOptout() {
            document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
            window[disableStr] = true;
        }

        if (!(navigator.doNotTrack == "1" || window.doNotTrack == "1")) {
            console.log("GA activated");

            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) { i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments) }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m) })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga'); ga('create', 'UA-114511820-1', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview'); ga('set', 'forceSSL', true); ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js'); ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true); ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

        } else {
            console.log("DNT activated, not tracking the user");
        }
        // Google Analytics END //

        

    };
    
    if (LinkedInPlatzhalter === 'true') {
            // LinkedIn START //
            var _linkedin_partner_id = "3518970"; window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || []; window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
            (function (l) { if (!l) { window.lintrk = function (a, b) { window.lintrk.q.push([a, b]) }; window.lintrk.q = [] } var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; var b = document.createElement("script"); b.type = "text/javascript"; b.async = true; b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s); })(window.lintrk);
            //var LinkedInNoScript = '<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display: none; " alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=3518970&fmt=gif" /></noscript>';
            //document.body.innerHTML += LinkedInNoScript;
            // LinkedIn END //
        }




    




    const declineFn = event => {
        declineStorage(storageType);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        var decision = "false";
    };

    const editFn = event => {
        editStorage(storageType);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        var decision = "edited";
    };

    acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);
    declineBtn.addEventListener('click', declineFn);
    editBtn.addEventListener('click', editFn);

    if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            consentPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```